# cant use function into another one from imported file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Dealing with a sapui5 client app. I'm trying to use a function from one common js file in another function  located in a controller js file but I'm getting a error "is not a function".

the controler file -> controller/controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "path/js/error"
], function(JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    onInit: function() {
        var type="servidor";
        var oModelServidores = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oDataModel.read('/ServersSet', {
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
               //do something
            },
            error: function(type, err) {
                errHandler(type,err);  //here I'm getting the error
            }
        });
}
});
```

the js file where is the function I want to use in controller -> js/error.js

```
function errHandler(type, err){
    var ErrorResponse = err.responseText;
    var ErrorResponseBody = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
    var msgError = ErrorResponseBody.error.message.value;

    switch(type) {
        case 'servidor':
            console.log('Ups! se ha producido un error a nivel de servidor: ' + msgError);
            break;
            default:
                console.log('Se ha producido un error inesperado');
    }
}
```

Any idea why getting this issue?

Comment: Is `js/error.js` and AMD module?

Answer (score 0):

`define` is an [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) convention and it looks like you are dealing with AMD modules.  You should read about how AMD works.  [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is one implementation of AMD.

The code

```
sap.ui.define(["path/js/error"], function (JSONModel) {...}
```

means: "load the file at `path/js/error` and populate what it returns into the variable `JSONModel`.

The way you have written your code means that `JSONModel` is either the reference that contains the function `errHandler` (if that is what is defined by `path/js/error`) or an Object that has a property that contains `errHandler`.

So, your code should look something like this instead:

**controller/controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "path/js/error"
], function (JSONModel) { // This is where the module defined by path/js/error is stored
    "use strict";

    onInit: function () {
        var type = "servidor";
        var oModelServidores = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oDataModel.read('/ServersSet', {
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function (type, err) {
                // Use the errHandler function of the dependency
                JSONModel(type, err);
                // or if errHandler is attached to an object that is returned
                JSONModel.errHandler(type, err)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**path/js/error.js**

```
define([], function () {
    return function errHandler(type, err) {
        var ErrorResponse = err.responseText;
        var ErrorResponseBody = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
        var msgError = ErrorResponseBody.error.message.value;

        switch (type) {
            case 'servidor':
                console.log('Ups! se ha producido un error a nivel de servidor: ' + msgError);
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Se ha producido un error inesperado');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: actually js/error.js is a simple js file where I want to store lot of functions to use in any function that I have in controller files. the thing is I'm totally new working with sapui5 and don't have very clear how to connect theses pieces in order to make them work properly. Your example looks nice and give me an idea of how should I code this

Comment: To add more, you should add JSONModel to the define as such `sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel`. It is not a best practice to name an external file as an SAPUI5 standard class. That way you'd have two defins: JSONModel and Error. After that, update `function(JSONModel, Error)` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you should import the js file at the beginning and give it a handle.
Your code should look like this:

```
    sap.ui.define([
        "path/js/error",
        "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
    ], function (Error, JSONModel) {...
...
      var oModelServidores = new JSONModel(); <-- note
...
      Error.errHandler(type, err)   <- you could call the handle to the js file something else
```

ensure the js file is in relative path you have specified